# Create Leveled JSON on Dataframe with a loop in python

Tags: python, json, dataframe, loops

I have an input dataframe in Python that gives certain transformations from a source table to a target table. This needs to be translated to a JSON with a certain format which i added below.

here is an example dataframe:

```
I have an input dataframe in Python that gives certain transformations. 



import pandas as pd

data = {'SourceDatabase':  ['SourceDB1', 'SourceDB2','SourceDB3'],
        'SourceSchema': ['SourceSchema1', 'SourceSchema2','SourceSchema3'],
        'SourceTable': ['SourceTable1', 'SourceTable2','SourceTable3'],
        'SourceColumn': ['SourceColumn1', 'SourceColumn2','SourceColumn3'],
        'TargetDatabase':  ['TargetDB1', 'TargetDB2','TargetDB3'],
        'TargetSchema': ['TargetSchema1', 'TargetSchema2','TargetSchema3'],
        'TargetTable': ['TargetTable1', 'TargetTable2','TargetTable3'],
        'TargetColumn': ['TargetColumn1', 'TargetColumn2','TargetColumn3'],
        'Mapping': ['Mapping1', 'Mapping2','Mapping3'],
        'SourceCode': ['SourceCode1', 'SourceCode2','SourceCode3']        
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The target JSON is:

```
 "lineages": [
     {
         "src_path": [
         {
             "SourceDatabase": "SourceDB1"
             },
         {
             "SourceSchema": "SourceSchema1"
         },
         {
             "SourceTable": "SourceTable1"
         },
         {
             "SourceColumn": "SourceColumn1"
         }
      ],
      "trg_path": [
         {
             "TargetDatabase": "TargetDB1"
         },
         {
             "TargetSchema": "TargetSchema1"
         },
         {
             "TargetTable": "TargetTable1"
         },
         {
             "TargetColumn": "TargetColumn1"
         }
      ],
      "Mapping": "Mapping1",
      "SourceCode": "SourceCode1"
     },
         {
         "src_path": [
         {
             "SourceDatabase": "SourceDB2"
             },
         {
             "SourceSchema": "SourceSchema2"
         },
         {
             "SourceTable": "SourceTable2"
         },
         {
             "SourceColumn": "SourceColumn2"
         }
      ],
      "trg_path": [
         {
             "TargetDatabase": "TargetDB2"
         },
         {
             "TargetSchema": "TargetSchema2"
         },
         {
             "TargetTable": "TargetTable2"
         },
         {
             "TargetColumn": "TargetColumn2"
         }
      ],
      "Mapping": "Mapping2",
      "SourceCode": "SourceCode2"
     }
```

How can i write a loop on this dataframe that fills (and adds the json part src_path and trg_path) with the corresponding values from the dataframe?

I tried a lot of different setups with loops, but it start to dizzle me.

Hope somebody is a killer loop writer here!

I Tried the following, but it is adding everything into one SRC and TRG_path. So, how can i break this up?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from json import loads, dumps

json = { 
    "lineages": [
        {
            "src_path": []
        },
        {
            "trg_path": []
        }
            
        
    ]
}

# src
for idx_rij, rij in df.iterrows():
    # val_row
    for idx_kolom, kolomnaam in enumerate(df.columns[0:4]):
        #print({kolomnaam: df[kolomnaam][idx_rij]})
        json["lineages"][0]["src_path"].append({kolomnaam: df[kolomnaam][idx_rij]})

        # trg
for idx_rij, rij in df.iterrows():
    # val_row
    for idx_kolom, kolomnaam in enumerate(df.columns[4:8]):
        #print({kolomnaam: df[kolomnaam][idx_rij]})
        json["lineages"][1]["trg_path"].append({kolomnaam: df[kolomnaam][idx_rij]})
               

print(dumps(json,indent=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify source and target column names to simplify the loop:

```py
src_cols = ["SourceDatabase", "SourceSchema", "SourceTable", "SourceColumn"]
trg_cols = ["TargetDatabase", "TargetSchema", "TargetTable", "TargetColumn"]

out = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    out.append(
        {
            "src_path": [{s: row[s]} for s in src_cols],
            "trg_path": [{t: row[t]} for t in trg_cols],
            "Mapping": row["Mapping"],
            "SourceCode": row["SourceCode"],
        }
    )

out = {"lineages": out}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "lineages": [
        {
            "src_path": [
                {"SourceDatabase": "SourceDB1"},
                {"SourceSchema": "SourceSchema1"},
                {"SourceTable": "SourceTable1"},
                {"SourceColumn": "SourceColumn1"},
            ],
            "trg_path": [
                {"TargetDatabase": "TargetDB1"},
                {"TargetSchema": "TargetSchema1"},
                {"TargetTable": "TargetTable1"},
                {"TargetColumn": "TargetColumn1"},
            ],
            "Mapping": "Mapping1",
            "SourceCode": "SourceCode1",
        },
        {
            "src_path": [
                {"SourceDatabase": "SourceDB2"},
                {"SourceSchema": "SourceSchema2"},
                {"SourceTable": "SourceTable2"},
                {"SourceColumn": "SourceColumn2"},
            ],
            "trg_path": [
                {"TargetDatabase": "TargetDB2"},
                {"TargetSchema": "TargetSchema2"},
                {"TargetTable": "TargetTable2"},
                {"TargetColumn": "TargetColumn2"},
            ],
            "Mapping": "Mapping2",
            "SourceCode": "SourceCode2",
        },
        {
            "src_path": [
                {"SourceDatabase": "SourceDB3"},
                {"SourceSchema": "SourceSchema3"},
                {"SourceTable": "SourceTable3"},
                {"SourceColumn": "SourceColumn3"},
            ],
            "trg_path": [
                {"TargetDatabase": "TargetDB3"},
                {"TargetSchema": "TargetSchema3"},
                {"TargetTable": "TargetTable3"},
                {"TargetColumn": "TargetColumn3"},
            ],
            "Mapping": "Mapping3",
            "SourceCode": "SourceCode3",
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej! works perfect, and good advice for next time to chop things up into smaller steps. Thanks again!